# What words are used to express the sincerity when texting your friends in festival period, such as the Spring Festival?

Tags: culture, word-lists

In the Chinese New Year period, many people will send text messages to their friends on the phone(via the SMS). I will also do that. When writing English letters, you may use "Yours," or "Sincerely," before your name, to show your sincerity.

So in Chinese, how can we express this meaning? I mean, when you say " I wish you [...]," what special words will be used to show your sincerity?

Comment: Are the expressions different from this event to any other part of the year?

Comment: No, it's the same when you want to express your wishes to someone in a formal way.

Comment: Remember that questions here will remain for a long time, so "in this period" won't mean anything in the future, I would recommend adding new year to the title.

Answer (score 1):

I received (and sent) several of these messages. I copied down some phrases to use later:

> 祝您事业兴旺！ = *May your career be prosperous!*
>
> 祝您福寿绵长！ = *I wish you a long & happy life!*
>
> 祝您龙年大吉！ = *I wish you a very lucky Dragon Year!*
>
> 祝您万事如意！ = *May everything be exactly as you wish it to be!*

From what I can tell, Chinese often string many different phrases together with commas, so you might get something like:

祝您龙年快乐，事业兴旺，福寿绵长，万事如意！

Answer (score 0):

```
此致

    敬礼
```

I think this is the equivalent form in chinese.

Update: the previous answer I gave was the way how we wrote in formal letters. For text message, I think the following form in chinese can accomplish the same function: [your name]敬上.

Comment: What are those ** **? Anyway, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I was trying to put some spaces there for indents, but apparently it didn't work.

Comment: Why indenting? I don't understand...

Comment: The words are used in short text messages(on the phone). I don't think "此致敬礼" is the choice. It's used in letters, I believe.

Comment: the 'Sincerely' thing was adapted from letters. so I think you can do the same in sms. or maybe some changed forms like: xxx敬上

Comment: I still don't understand the indenting....

Comment: Agree with xxx敬上 but not 此致 敬礼